# How to check boost socket write_some method ends or not

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, boost-asio

I am trying to send some data by using boost socket.
TCPClient class's role is to make a connection cna can send data throw sendMessage method.

When I executed under code it does not work. However, it works when I debug it.
I think the problem is timing.

delete[] msg; works before sending msg.(just my thought)

so, I want to check whether msg is sent or not.
or any other good way.

client main() code

```
TCPClient *client = new TCPClient(ip, port);
client->sendMessage((char *)msg, 64 + headerLength + bodyLength);
delete[] msg;
```

under code is snedMessage method.

```
void TCPClient::sendMessage(const char *message, int totalLength) throw(boost::system::system_error) {

if(false == isConnected())
    setConnection();

boost::system::error_code error;
this->socket.get()->write_some(boost::asio::buffer(message, totalLength), error);

if(error){
        //do something
}
```

}

Comment: what does "does not work" mean? the data isn't sent, there is an error? We need a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Your `sendMessage()` function is written incorrectly. You cannot expect that socket will send all of your data at once, you need a loop where you try to send, check how many bytes were sent, offset buffer (and update `totalLength` accordingly of course) if necessary and repeat until all data is sent. Or interrupt if there is error condition. You try to send only once, ignore result and assume that if there is no error then all data was sent. This is not a case. Stream socket may send one or two or whatever amount of bytes at a time, and your code needs to handle that.

Your code should be something like this:

```
while( totalLength ) {
    boost::system::error_code error;
    auto sz = this->socket.get()->write_some(boost::asio::buffer(message, totalLength), error);

    if(error){
        //do something and interrupt the loop
    }
    totalLength -= sz;
    message += sz;
}
```

Comment: or just use `asio::write` which does all this for you: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/write/overload1.html

Comment: @AlanBirtles hmm, it requires `SyncWriteStream`, does socket satisfy that?

Comment: yep it does, its what it was written for. the requirements are here: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/SyncWriteStream.html just needs `write_some`